# What are positive and negative circles in weighted digraph?

Tags: graphs

I am going through Warshall and Floyd algorithms and I read that Floyd's algorithm does not hold if a graph has negative circle. I have not been able to fully figure out what  negative circle means. Therefore, I would like to know  more about positive and negative circles.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A *circle* is a path in the graph ($v\to u_1 \to u_2 \to \cdots \to v$) starting from some node $v$, that goes back to node $v$, thus "closing a circle".

The "value" of a circle, is the sum of the weights of the edges in the circle. If they sum to a negative value -- the circle is "negative"; otherwise, it is "positive".

Comment: I should have figured this out by myself, poor soul.

Comment: So, if I do currency trading(moving from one to the other and finally to the start currency) a positive circle means that I will make money. It that correct?

Comment: @user618677, please don't use the comments to ask new questions.  This is a question-and-answer site, not a discussion forum, and on this site, comments exist mainly to help people improve their questions/answers.  If you have a follow-on question and you've put a substantial amount of effort into it, you can ask a new question (but fair warning: that particular question might not be well-received, because I suspect if you work through a few examples you'll be able to work out the answer on your own).  Thank you!

Comment: DW, no need of trying to be polite here. I am just trying to internalizing some basic concepts and build up my own understanding.